# Узнать количество символов в массиве BYTE

Tags: c, windows

Узнать количество символов в строке можно так:

```
TCHAR* someStr = "Hello World!";
size_t sizeStr = strlen(someStr);
```

Как узнать количество символов в массиве байт, например:

```
BYTE * someByte = "\xFF\xAA\x55";
size_t sizeByte = strlen((TCHAR*)someByte );
```

Работает не корректно, особенно при юникоде. Как быть?

Comment: Для разных типов строк разные функции. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78zh94ax.aspx

Comment: @alexolut, спасибо помог, вынеси свой ответ в "в ответ", я помечу галочкой, чтобы закрыть тему-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разных типов строк следует использовать разные функции.

С описанием можно ознакомиться в документации на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78zh94ax.aspx)

Comment: когда идет массив байт "\x55\x00\xFF" и вызвать функцию _mbslen - то она вернет "1", а не 3, почему она обрывает счет если идет нулевой байт? функция думает что это конец или что?

Comment: @Duracell нулевой байт в мультибайтовой строке является признаком конца, поэтому и возвращается `1`, т.е. учитывается только символ `\x55`.

Comment: я так понимаю, что если в моем массиве байт есть нулевые байты корректно подсчитать количество символов не получится?

Comment: @Duracell все упомянутые функции подсчета символов опираются на наличие специального терминирующего символа. Если такой символ встречается, то тут функция подсчета длины и остановится. Может быть нужно просто отказаться от нультерминированных строк и использовать массивы символов?

Comment: нет мне нужно подсчитать именно в массиве BYTE символы

Comment: @Duracell `BYTE` это по сути синоним типа `unsigned char`. Скорее всего строки тут действительно не нужны. Надо использовать массивы.  Например `BYTE someByte[] = "\xFF\xAA\x55";` с последующим `sizeof(someByte)/sizeof(BYTE)` для получения кол-ва элементов типа `BYTE`.

Answer (score 4):

Юникод бывает разный:

## мультибайтный (utf-8)

Для него подойдет стандартный ASCII-Z подход и класс std::string
Но при этом, будет считаться не длина строки в символах, а количество байт.

Работа на уровне символов с utf-8 стандартом C++ не поддерживается - нужны внешние библиотеки.

## двухбайтный (utf-16)

Тут поможет тип wchar_t* и класс std::wstring, остальное по аналогии с ASCII-Z, только признаком конца строки будет слово (16 бит), равное 0.

Для этих строк существуют аналоги восьмибитных функций из стандартной библиотеки C, для измерения длины - `wcslen()`, например

При этом, работа  этих аналогов будет происходить как раз на уровне символов.

## четырехбайтный (utf-32)

стандартной библиотекой C++ не поддерживается.

Comment: В случае utf-8 вы так получите количество байт, но не количество символов, нет?

Comment: @Harry - внес уточнение, спасибо.

Comment: Что-то я не могу найти в сях `wstrlen`. Можно ссылку?

Comment: @alexolut, я внес правку

Comment: А разве под стандартным линуксом `wchar_t` не 32-битный? (Не уверен.)

Answer (score 1):

```
wchar_t* wstr1 = L"Count.";
wprintf(L"Length of '%s' : %d\n", wstr1, wcslen(wstr1) );
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score -1):

Ты задаешь этот вопрос, потому что не понимаешь базовых вещей.

Надо для начала понять, что такое обычная строка
[image: как выглядит обычная строка]

Видишь указатель = 4 байта, которые указывают на массив данных на самом деле.

strlen() - работает так, он бежит по массиву и ищет \0 (конец строки), т.е. strlen() - это просто функция подсчета элементов.

Дальше еще интереснее..

Если ты говоришь об юникоде. То у него структура совсем другая.

Обычно используется вспомогательный класс, например CString. Его структура приблизительно такая.

[image: приблизительно так]

- char (для символьных строк ANSI).
- wchar_t (для символьных строк в юникоде).
- TCHAR (и для символьных строк ANSI и юникод).

Т.е. видишь что? Это разные совсем структуры. И у них разная функция. Для wchar_t(юникод) используй wslen() как то так что ли называется..

Кстати еще у компилятора есть,  деректива в настройках. Какой тип будет по умолчанию ansi или unicode. Советую ставить unicode.

**Насчет твоего примера.**

Он изначально сделан криво. Скорее всего ты либо получаешь из сокета строку, либо из файла читаешь.

Читай в буфер, а сразу в нормальную структуру, какую нибудь CString.

Comment: Минус мой, за панибратский стиль журнала "Хакер".
И за совет использовать CString из покойного MFC, который вспоминать страшно.

Comment: Во первых, MFC не покойный. Единственная у него достойная альтернатива WTL. Однако и там и там есть свои достоинства и недостатки. Во вторых CString был приведен как пример(даже специально обозначено) - главное не конкретный пример а смысл уловить..

Comment: @hitcode, базу знаю, знаю что на юникод занимает 2 байты, просто не дочитал msdn + есть еще нюанс, когда идет массив байт "\x55\x00\xFF" и вызвать функцию _mbslen - то она вернет "1", а не 3, сейчас сижу разбираюсь почему она так странно считает

Comment: @Duracell, Потому что она показывает тебе сколько занимает твой 1 указатель = 1 символ. А тебе надо сделать, ссылку на строку.. Смотрим первую картиночку. Ты выводишь маленький квадратик, а тебе надо всю строку.